# How to turn json data into hyperlink within get request?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I have a get request which grabs documents and saves the 4 values I need into key/value pairs.

Howerver I need one of the key/values to be a hyperlink (A href).

Get request:

```
.then(response => 
    response.data.d.query.PrimaryQueryResult.RelevantResults.Table.Rows.results.map(document => ({
      name: document.Cells.results[3].Value,
      path: document.Cells.results[6].Value.replace('https://bpk.sharepoint.com', ''),
      view: document.Cells.results[6].Value, 
      site:document.Cells.results[36].Value.split("/").pop()
    }))
  )
```

`view: document.Cells.results[6].Value` <<< This needs to be a hyperlink as this data is used in a react table and the link needs to be clickable and take you to the file.

Table:

```
  <Table className="table" data={this.state.documents} sortable={true} itemsPerPage={10} pageButtonLimit={5} />
```

Any idea how to do this within the get request?!

Comment: Assuming the result is stored in `state` and rendered, why not use `<a href={view}>...</a>` in render()?

Comment: @ChrisG Updated the orginal post. The table just takes in a data object >.<

Comment: Ok, so you can probably do this then: `view: <a href={document.Cells.results[6].Value}>File</a>,` - can you link us to the `Table` component you're using?

Comment: <a href={document.Cells.results[6].Value}>File</a> <<< Going to give this a go then!

https://www.npmjs.com/package/reactable

Comment: No, don't add together parts like that. You can use exactly what I posted in my comment, as-is. It's JSX and works anywhere, not just in the render() function.

Comment: Yeah I just saw your code and updated my comment loool sorry still getting my head around all this jsx es6 goodness! It worked perfect btw thank you :D